Ideals of the upper-triangular matrix algebra $\mathcal{T}_n$ over $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$
Let $\Bbb{F}$ be the field of all real or complex numbers and let $\mathcal{T}_n$ be the algebra of all upper-triangular $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb{F}$. Can one completely describe all (two-sided) ideals of $\mathcal{T}_n$?
My attempt:
For fixed $1 \le i \le j \le n$ denote
$$\mathcal{I}_{i,j} := \operatorname{span}\{E_{rs} : r \le i, j \le s\} \le \mathcal{T}_n.$$
It is easy to check that $\mathcal{I}_{i,j}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{T}_n$. Clearly, (vector space) sums of such ideals are also ideals of $\mathcal{T}_n$. For example, the ideal of all strictly upper-triangular matrices in this notation could be represented as
$$\mathcal{I}_{1,2} + \mathcal{I}_{2,3} + \cdots + \mathcal{I}_{n-1,n}.$$
Are the sums of $\mathcal{I}_{i,j}$ the only ideals of $\mathcal{T}_n$?
Suppose that $\mathcal{I}$ is a nonzero ideal of $\mathcal{T}_n$. Let $A \in \mathcal{I}$ be a nonzero matrix. If $A_{ij} \ne 0$, then using matrix units one obtains
$$A_{ij}E_{ij} = E_{ii}AE_{jj} \in \mathcal{I} \implies E_{ij} \in \mathcal{I}$$
and from here one easily shows that $\mathcal{I}_{i,j} \subseteq \mathcal{I}$.  Therefore, it seems that $\mathcal{I}$ would be the sum of all $\mathcal{I}_{i,j}$ with the property that there exists a matrix $A \in \mathcal{I}$ with a nonzero entry at the position $(i,j)$. Could anyone help me finish this argument? Or to maybe find a better way to describe all ideals?

I think the description for any field is going to be the same.  I'm pretty sure one can adapt the usual description of right and left ideals for a triangular matrix ring.
For your upper triangular ring $T$ you can take the idempotent $e=e_{11}$ and $R,M,S$ to be $R=eTe=F$, $S=(1-e)T(1-e)=T_{n-1}(F)$ and $M=eT(1-e)$, which decomposes it as a vector space.  $S$ is of course the triangular matrix ring of one less size.  You could have used "bigger" idempotents that make larger corner rings, but it seems to me that making one just $F$ is prudent in terms of figuring the rest out.
This gives a similar decomposition of $I$ as $eIe\oplus eI(1-e)\oplus (1-e)I(1-e)$ (call them $I_1, I_2, I_3$ respectively) where $I_1\lhd R$, $I_3\lhd S$ and $I_2$ is an $R,S$ bimodule satisfying both $I_1M\subseteq I_2$ and $MI_3\subseteq I_2$.  Conversely any such choice of $I_1, I_2, I_3$  yields an ideal of $T$.
So the bulk of the work seems to be in reasoning what $I_2$ can be, perhaps even in terms of the flag associated with $T$.  This might get you a recursive description that looks plausible when you write it out in terms of matrices.
It also seems highly likely that this has been determined before.  I myself was unable to track down something in writing, but don't let that keep you from searching yourself.
Regarding the linked solution
I assume that the linked solution means $n_{ij}$ where it wrote $d_{ij}$ and similarly in the earlier blog post it may have plagiarized. It looks like the same argument will work for any PID, namely one like a field $F$. In that case, the $n_{ij}$ will all be $0$ or $1$.
I struggle to find a simple way to say this but it would say that if an ideal $I\subseteq R=T_n(F)$ has an element that is nonzero on $a_{ij}$ then the ideal also contains all single-nonzero entry matrices in row $i$ between columns $j$ and $n$, and all single-nonzero entry matrices in column $j$ between rows $1$ and $i$. (Or $0$ and $i$ if you are $0$ indexed.)

Thank you very much. I was sort of hoping for a more elementary approach, something like this, only this was over $\Bbb{Z}$.

@mechanodroid Does that answer make sense to you? Are the $n_{ij}$'s related to the $d_{ij}$'s?  Perhaps they were meant to be the same thing. If so, then it should also hold for a PID like a field $F$, in which case the $n_{ij}$'s can all be taken to be $0$ or $1$.  That certainly does line up with the intuition that the ideals migrate entries "up" and "right".

Your last paragraph precisely means that $\mathcal{I}{i,j} \subseteq \mathcal{I}$ using the notation from my question. It remains to see exactly which positions $(i,j)$ such that $A{ij} \ne 0$ for some $A \in \mathcal{I}$ are possible. Then $\mathcal{I}$ would be equal to $\sum \mathcal{I}_{i,j}$ where $i,j$ go over this set of positions. I hope I'm making sense. Is an arbitrary selection of $(i,j)$ possible?

Also, it is possible you misunderstood me, nowhere did I claim that the answer I linked was satisfactory or that it indeed made any sense (it isn't and it doesn't). All the worse if it was indeed plagiarized (which seems likely because of the same error occurring in both). I was just trying to give an example of an elementary approach I was hoping was possible to be conducted, but in a correct way.

@mechanodroid Well I was literally asking if you had the same confusion I had about it. It wasn't rhetorical. But if the $n_{ij}=d_{ij}$ then I think it may well be correct. In fact, I think it becomes equivalent to my answer if you consider the cases (that $I_1$ has to be either $F$ or $0$ and when it's $F$ it has to contain the remainder of the row to satisfy $I_1M\subseteq I_2$.)

I have a hard time expressing it any better than "the shape of the edge of the ideal does not have grooves." which seems a bit nonsensical at first.
